# Apostrophe in Verilog array assignment

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I've seen a Verilog example that assigns values to an array as follows :

```
array = '{'{0,1,2,3},'{4,5,6,7},'{8,9,10,11}};
```

What's the purpose of the apostrophe **(')** ?
How will this be any different ?

```
array = {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11}};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SystemVerilog has the array assignment operator `'{...}` in addition to the concatenation operator `{...}`.

Concatentation is for packed arrays - basically you combine multiple signals into a single bus.

```
wire [7:0] a = {4'd7, 4'd14};
```

You can nest concatenation operators too. The following assigns the same value to `b` as was assigned to `a` in the previous example. Nested concatenations flatten out to a single bus.

```
wire [7:0] b = {{1'b0,1'b1,1'b1,1'b1},{1'b1,1'b1,1'b1,1'b0}};
```

---

Array assignment is for unpacked arrays:

```
integer c [0:3] = '{0, 1, 2, 3};
```

Arrays can also be multi-dimensional, in which case you can initialise each dimension (from right to left) by nesting array assignments:

```
integer d [0:3][0:2] = '{'{0,1,2,3},'{4,5,6,7},'{8,9,10,11}};
```

---

You can also combine the two (concatentation and array assignment):

```
wire [7:0] e [0:3] = '{{4'd7, 4'd14}, 8'd1, {4'd5, 4'd3}, 8'd3};
```

---

---

On to your two examples.

The first example is of array initialisation. This would assign `array[0][0] = 0`, `array[1][0] = 1` and so on, e.g. `array[0][1] = 4` and `array[3][2] = 11`. For example, it could be used to initialise an unpacked array, such as:

```
integer array [0:3][0:2] = '{'{0,1,2,3},'{4,5,6,7},'{8,9,10,11}}; //Valid
```

In the second example, you are concatenating twelve 32-bit numbers (*) together, which would result in a single 384 bit number. This could be assigned to a packed array, but not an unpacked array:

```
wire [383:0] array = {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11}}; //Valid
integer array [0:3][0:2] = {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11}}; //Invalid
```

---

(*) Note, these are technically unsized literals, so the concatenation is not strictly legal, though most synthesis tools will treat them as 32-bit values and allow the concatentation (possibly with warnings). Always use size specifiers on your literals when performing concatenation.

Comment: Just a note: the statement `wire [383:0] array = {{0,1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9,10,11}};` is illegal according to the LRM. You are not allowed to have a packed array concatenation with unsized literals. Some tools allow this to pass through with a warning but you're really setting yourself up for trouble if you write `{v1,0,v2}` exepecting a single digit 0 in between v1 and v2
`

Comment: @dave_59 most things will interpret the size as 32-bit, but yes, I totally agree that the using unsized literals is a recipe for pain and not guaranteed to work. I've added a note.